# Flask Error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'https'

Tags: python, jinja2

So, I'm trying to make a web application with Python and Flask. When running the webpage, it gives me that error, pointing to my fonts line. It says the error is in this line:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Found nothing on Google. Related issues but not one single like this one. The line was extracted from google webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was in the line before, where I didn't close the curly brackets.